# How to get rid of top fading edge in android full screen mode?

Tags: android, fullscreen

By putting the following two lines of code in activity.OnCreate, I can get a full screen view:

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

However, if you look carefully, there is still a slight fading edge on the top edge of the screen which looks like a residue of the removed title bar. How can I get rid of that completely?

See this screen capture, which is a fullscreen view obtained using the above two lines of code, but the top fading edge is visible and annoying, I already tried android:fadingEdge="none"  and android:fadingEdgeLength="0sp" on the root view of this activity, doesn't work:
[image: A fullscreen view with a green background, fading edge is visible]

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you asking for:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```