# Android Fullscreen codes not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using these lines to get full screen, but the bar for Battery and Antenna is still there.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

I even checked a line mentioned in [How to get rid of top fading edge in android full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524607/how-to-get-rid-of-top-fading-edge-in-android-full-screen-mode)
When I add that (`setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);`), screen goes up, but it's kinda like the bar is on top of my screen.
I naturally assume that the OS (Android 4.0.4) does not allow that, but I was said that this code will force it to be like that, nevertheless it's not working, the final code to be more precise is this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }
```

Would you please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show app in fullscreen use:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To remove it use:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Change your `FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN` to `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

Comment: Yep! I got that. I made a mistake. :) I would have voted up for you, but my reputation does not allow it.

Comment: @yousefyegane No problem, glad you got it sorted out ;)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Seems like you have everything right except you have the flag `FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN` twice

First, make sure your theme does not include an actionbar. Then, add the following in onCreate:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: It was twice in every code I've seen, here too, from others. I don't know why though.

Comment: Once is to clear the flag of the non-fullscreen mode. Then the other is to add the full screen mode flag.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing every thing right the code is simple  for getting the full screen

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //if you want it too other vice first one is good enough
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**

> Note please add it before setContentView

**

Comment: @ghosttalker why did you put `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` in your code? it has nothing to do with his question

Answer (score 1):

for Full Screen of Activity You should have to use below code before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or If you are using Theme.AppCompat in your application you can use FullScreenTheme by adding below style in style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
 parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

> and also mention in your manifest file

```
    <activity
      android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Also, i attach you a related question:

[Using new IMMERSIVE mode in android kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135445/using-new-immersive-mode-in-android-kitkat)

Comment: I am using API 8. It seems it's for API 19